# Standalone page for anonymous comment thread

Tags: collaboration, comment-system

I'm looking for a website where I can get a private sharable link like website.com/9b8f3s98 which is a page with just a comment thread, where people can anonymously add comments and replies. So imagine a Reddit post but just the comments.

So far the best I've found is a Google Doc, which isn't ideal because it's unstructured.